# Apache Kafka / How to rolling upgrade to 0.10.2.0 with docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I use [kafka-docker](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker) version 0.9 and wish to upgrade to 0.010.2.0.

Following the instructions for rolling upgrade, I should update `server.properties` with `inter.broker.protocol.version` and `log.message.format.version` properties, and then shut down the broker, update the code and restart it.

I don't understand how the rolling upgrade works via docker. I see that `server.properties` isn't exposed via the docker, and there is no meaning to update it before cause the docker will be deleted and then install again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`server.properties` values are exposed by Environment Variables: https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/master/start-kafka.sh following this code `sed -r "s/KAFKA_(.*)=.*/\1/g" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr _ .` you will need something like `KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL_VERSION` and `KAFKA_LOG_MESSAGE_FORMAT_VERSION`